# confluent_kafka python error "Unsupported value "SASL_SSL" for configuration property "security.protocol": OpenSSL not available at build time"}

Tags: python, apache-kafka, librdkafka, confluent-kafka-python

I am writing a Avro Python Producer and when I try to run the code I get this error:
`cimpl.KafkaException: KafkaError{code=_INVALID_ARG,val=-186,str="Unsupported value "SASL_SSL" for configuration property "security.protocol": OpenSSL not available at build time"}`

I can't seem to find anywhere how to solve this when using `confluent_kafka python` module. It seems like it is related to a certificate issue but I am still struggling to grasp what's truly happening here and how to solve this.

I installed `librdkafka` using homebrew and I installed `confluent_kafka` using `pip3`. I am on an M1 Macbook.

Comment: It doesn't sound like a certificate issue at all.  It's sounds like a "built without OpenSSL" issue -- the error message says as much.  The solutions to such an issue would be (1) don't try to use SSL, or (2) rebuild the component involved (probably librdkafka) with SSL support or (3) get the needed library already built from a third party.  I'm afraid I can't offer specific instructions for your particular environment.

Comment: I rebuilt librdkafka with SSL support and still the same error. Not sure what else to do at this point, I need to use SSL. I wonder if librdkafka is just not optimized to be used on an M1 Mac and that's the issue.

Comment: It's not a matter of "optimized". I believe the is an open Github issue requesting ARM builds